# Suggestions for better implementation of Python Temperature convertor

Tags: python-3.x

I completed a temperature convert in python and noticed that much of the code was repetitive. What I want is to give it a cleaner appearance and think the use arrays along with a function or two I could bring the lines of code from about 500  to 150.

Below I will post a sample of the code. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

```
    #---Program by Zakar H.---#
    #--- TO DO ---#
    #1. Fix equations for rankine,delisle, newton, reaumer, and romer.
    #2. Code seems repetitive. Maybe use arrays, functions or dictionary.

    #Provides an introduction to the game
    print("ZvH Temperature Convertor\n")

    #Lets user know what values to enter for the conversion type
    def convertor():
             print("What temperature are you converting from?")
             print("Enter 1 for Celcius\nEnter 2 for Fahrenheit\nEnter 3 for Kelvin\nEnter 4 for Rankine")
             print("Enter 5 for Delisle\nEnter 6 for Newton\nEnter 7 for Reaumer\nEnter 8 for Romer")
             #Gets user input for conversion type
             user_input = input('''''')

    #If 1 is selected it starts conversion from Celcius
    if user_input == ("1"):
            def celsius():
                    print("\nWhat temperature are you converting too?")
                    print("Enter 1 for Celcius\nEnter 2 for Fahrenheit\nEnter 3 for Kelvin\nEnter 4 for Rankine")
                    print("Enter 5 for Delisle\nEnter 6 for Newton\nEnter 7 for Reaumer\nEnter 8 for Romer")                
                    #Gets user input for converting
                    type = input('''''')
                    #COnverts to celcius
                    if type == ("1"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(temp)
                    #Converts to fahrenheit
                    elif type == ("2"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            fahrenheit = temp * (9.0/5.0) + 32
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)
                    #Converts to Kelvin
                    elif type == ("3"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            kelvin = temp + 273.15
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(kelvin)
                    #Converts to Rankine
                    elif type == ("4"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            rankine = (temp + 273.15) * (9.0/5.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(rankine)
                    #Converts to Delisle
                    elif type == ("5"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            delisle = (100 - temp) * (3.0/2.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(delisle)
                    #Converts to Newton
                    elif type == ("6"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            newton = temp * (33.0/100.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(newton)
                    #Converts to Reaumur
                    elif type == ("7"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            reaumur = temp * (4.0/5.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(reaumur)
                    #Converts to Romer
                    elif type == ("8"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            romer = temp * (9.0/5.0) + 7.5
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(romer)
            celsius()

    #If 2 is selected it starts conversion from Fahrenheit
    if user_input == ("2"):
            def fahrenheit():
                    print("\nWhat temperature are you converting too?")
                    print("Enter 1 for Celcius\nEnter 2 for Fahrenheit\nEnter 3 for Kelvin\nEnter 4 for Rankine")
                    print("Enter 5 for Delisle\nEnter 6 for Newton\nEnter 7 for Reaumer\nEnter 8 for Romer")                
                    #Gets user input for converting
                    fahrenheit_type = input('''''')
                    #Converts to celcius
                    if fahrenheit_type == ("1"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            fahrenheit = (temp - 32) * (5.0/9.0)
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)
                    #Converts to fahrenheit
                    elif fahrenheit_type == ("2"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(temp)
                    #Converts to Kelvin
                    elif fahrenheit_type == ("3"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            fahrneheit = (temp + 459.67) * (5.0/9.0)
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)
                    #Converts to Rankine
                    elif fahrenheit_type == ("4"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            fahrenheit = temp + 459.67 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)
                    #Converts to Delisle
                    elif fahrenheit_type == ("5"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            fahrenheit = (212 - temp) * (5.0/6.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)
                    #Converts to Newton
                    elif fahrenheit_type == ("6"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            fahrenheit = (temp - 32) * (11.0/60.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)
                    #Converts to Reaumur
                    elif fahrenheit_type == ("7"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            fahrenheit = (temp -32) * (4.0/9.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)
                    #Converts to Romer
                    elif fahrenheit_type == ("8"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            fahrenheit = (temp + 32) * (7.0/24.0) + 32 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)    
            fahrenheit()

    #If 3 is selected it starts conversion from kelvin
    if user_input == ("3"):
            def kelvin():
                    print("\nWhat temperature are you converting too?")
                    print("Enter 1 for Celcius\nEnter 2 for Fahrenheit\nEnter 3 for Kelvin\nEnter 4 for Rankine")
                    print("Enter 5 for Delisle\nEnter 6 for Newton\nEnter 7 for Reaumer\nEnter 8 for Romer")                
                    #Gets user input for converting
                    kelvin_type = input('''''')
                    #Converts to celcius
                    if kelvin_type == ("1"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            kelvin = temp - 273.15 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(kelvin)
                    #Converts to fahrenheit
                    if kelvin_type == ("2"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            kelvin = temp * (9.0/5.0) - 489.67
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(fahrenheit)
                    #Converts to Kelvin
                    elif kelvin_type == ("3"):
                            kelvin = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated\n")
                            print(kelvin)
                    #Converts to Rankine
                    elif kelvin_type == ("4"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            kelvin = temp * (9.0/5.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(kelvin)
                    #Converts to Delisle
                    elif kelvin_type == ("5"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            kelvin = (375.15 - temp) * (3.0/2.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(kelvin)
                    #Converts to Newton
                    elif kelvin_type == ("6"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            kelvin = (temp - 273.15) * (33.0/100.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(kelvin)
                    #Converts to Reaumur
                    elif kelvin_type == ("7"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            kelvin = (temp - 273.15) * (4.0/5.0) 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(kelvin)
                    #Converts to Romer
                    elif kelvin_type == ("8"):
                            temp = int(input('''\nType the value for conversion.\n'''))
                            kelvin = (temp - 273.15) * (21.0/40.0) + 7.5 
                            print("\nThe conversion calculated")
                            print(romer)    
            kelvin()
```

Comment: this question may better be suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . and please consider posting the conversion of fewer different scales; you can then extend the ideas to the full use cases you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the response and Ill post there in the future. Also what do you mean by your second sentence "the conversion of fewer or lesser scales"

Comment: my guess is that  @hiro means that you should start with a couple of temperature scales e.g., `temperature_scales = "Celsius Fahrenheit".split()`, test your script, make sure it works, and only then add more scales and the corresponding conversion functions.

Comment: I see now. I didn't understand but now I do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temperature_scales = ("Celsius Fahrenheit Kelvin Rankine "
                      "Delisle Newton Reaumur Romer").split()

def get_number(prompt, *, min=float('-inf'), max=float('inf'), number_type=float):
    """Ask user for a number in [min, max] range."""
    while True:
        try:
            i = number_type(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if min <= i <= max:
                return i
        print("Enter %s in the range [%s, %s]" % (number_type.__name__, min, max))

def get_scale(prompt):
    """Ask user for a temperature scale name."""
    choices = "\n".join(["Enter %d for %s" % i_v
                         for i_v in enumerate(temperature_scales, start=1)])
    i = get_number("".join([prompt, "\n", choices, "\n? "]),
                   min=1, max=len(temperature_scales), number_type=int)
    return temperature_scales[i-1]

from_scale = get_scale("What temperature scale are you converting from?")
to_scale = get_scale("What temperature scale are you converting to?")
from_temp = get_number("Type the temperature value for conversion\n? ")
to_temp = converter(from_scale, to_scale)(from_temp)
print("The conversion calculated %.2f" % to_temp)
```

Now, all what is left is to define the `converter` function:

```
def converter(from_scale, to_scale):
    """Return a function that converts from *from_scale* to *to_scale*."""
    def f(temperature):
        return from_kelvin[to_scale](to_kelvin[from_scale](temperature))
    f.__name__ = "convert%sTo%s" % (from_scale, to_scale)
    return f

def celsius_to_kelvin(temperature):
    return temperature + 273.15

def celsius_from_kelvin(temperature):
    return temperature - 273.15

def fahrenheit_to_kelvin(temperature):
    return (temperature + 459.67) * 5 / 9

def fahrenheit_from_kelvin(temperature):
    return (temperature * 9 / 5.) - 459.67

from_kelvin = dict(Celsius=celsius_from_kelvin, Fahrenheit=fahrenheit_from_kelvin)
to_kelvin = dict(Celsius=celsius_to_kelvin, Fahrenheit=fahrenheit_to_kelvin)
```

Define other `"{scale}_to_kelvin()"` and `"{scale}_from_kelvin()"` functions and add them to the dictionaries.

If all converter functions are defined; you could generate the dictionaries automatically:

```
kelvin_to_kelvin = kelvin_from_kelvin = lambda temperature: temperature
to_kelvin = {scale: globals()[scale.lower() + "_to_kelvin"]
             for scale in temperature_scales}
from_kelvin = {scale: globals()[scale.lower() + "_from_kelvin"]
               for scale in temperature_scales}
```

Or you could provide the converter functions manually inline using `lambda`:

```
from_kelvin = {
    "Celsius": lambda t: t - 273.15,
    "Fahrenheit": lambda t: (t * 9 / 5.) - 459.67
}
```

You don't need to define `C_to_F()` function if `C_to_kelvin()` and `F_from_kelvin()` are defined. It allows to define less conversion functions: if there are N temperature scales then you only need to define `2*N` converter functions (from/to) instead of `N*N` functions i.e., 16 instead of 64 in this case.

GUI (or ncurses) interface would be more convenient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

this would be my first shot at it. *WARNING*: i copy-pasted the conversions from your code and will probably have gotten the wrong ones; did not check any of them.

```
def fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    return  fahrenheit * (9.0/5.0) + 32

def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
    return (celsius - 32) * (5.0/9.0)

def kelvin_to_celsius(kelvin):
    return kelvin - 273.15

def fahrenheit_to_kelvin(fahrenheit):
    return fahrenheit * (9.0/5.0) - 489.67

convertor_functions = {
    'fc': fahrenheit_to_celsius,
    'cf': celsius_to_fahrenheit,
    'kc': kelvin_to_celsius,
    'ck': lambda celsius: celsius + 273.15,
    'kf': lambda kelvin: (kelvin + 459.67) * (5.0/9.0)
    }


def handle_intput():
    '''
    read in input of the form "273k in c" return (273, kc)
    '''
    print("convert temp -- syntax: '46k in f' (empty string to quit)")
    input_str = input('convert? ')
    if not input_str:
        return None
    in_temp, target_unit = input_str.split('in')
    target_unit = target_unit.strip()
    in_temp = in_temp.strip()
    orig_unit = in_temp[-1]
    orig_temp = float(in_temp[:-1])
    convert_str = orig_unit + target_unit
    return orig_temp, convert_str

def convert(orig_temp, convert_str):
    '''
    orig_temp: integer; convert_str: kc (-> kelvin to celsius, etc)
    '''
    convert_f = convertor_functions[convert_str]
    return convert_f(orig_temp)

while True:
    ret = handle_intput()
    if ret is None:
        print('ok, bye!')
        break
    orig_temp, convert_str = ret
    orig_unit = convert_str[0]
    target_unit = convert_str[1]
    target_temp = convert(orig_temp, convert_str)
    print('{}{} = {:3.3f}{}'.format(orig_temp, orig_unit, 
                                    target_temp, target_unit))
```

to my taste it is sometimes good practice to convert long `if/elif/else` sequences into a dictionary - as i have done for your conversion functions. `convertor_functions[kc]` now returns the function that converts from kelvin to celsius and `convertor_functions[kc](kelvin)` does the calculation.

note that the conversion functions can easily be written as `lambda` expressions (as i have for `'ck'` and `'kf'`) - which may help if you want the code to be short.